# Returning a service type in WCF

Tags: wcf

I have 2 service interfaces A and B. In A I define
B GetB()

problem is I can't just return an interface type in WCF since it's not serializable. How do I tell WCF that this is a service?

Comment: I don't see any good reason why you want to return a **service** as the value from another service call ..... that seems a bit odd .... what are you trying to accomplish with this??

Comment: Well if you consider how html work, you can return links to other html pages. Basically html pages are data + code in that sense. I might want to create a service factory. Say I have the option of hosting 2 different service implementations and want some way of dynamically referring users to either one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This link](http://weblogs.asp.net/avnerk/archive/2006/07/31/WCF-Serialization-part-1_3A00_-Interfaces_2C00_-Base-classes-and-the-NetDataContractFormatSerializer.aspx) states:

> When the service receives the messages and tries to deserialize the message (interface) parameter, it's stuck - there's no way to create an abstract IMessage from the serialized data, and the data carries no information on how to deserialize it.

The same blog also gives two possible solutions to the problem, but not sure if it is suitable for your purposes. Please check it out.